# how is the report owner set?

Tags: reporting, lookup, fields

In apex there's a field called ownerId on reports, that in some instances points to the folder that it's located in. How is this field set? Is it always going to be the folder that the report is placed in?

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_report.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reports come in 3 flavors.

1. "My Personal Custom Reports" folder -> owner id = your id. These reports are invisible to  anybody else (even SysAdmins)
2. "Unfiled Public reports" - reports that aren't stored in any folder. OwnerId = organisation's id (Setup -> Company information for example)
3. reports in folders - ownerid = folder's id.

Yes, that means that once report goes public it stops to matter who created it (creator doesn't get any special rights because of that). Anybody that has read/edit access to the folder will be able to use/modify all reports stored there (of course ignoring the profile-based rights to objects reported on).

Comment: can you point me to some documentation that spells out some of this nitty gritty details?

Comment: I wish it'd be some (easily available) documentation... I'm afraid it's "own experience and gray hair gained" :D Thoroughly tested with SOQL (and in case of #1 with Metadata API as well as hardcore url hacking tricks). Thank `{!$GOD}` it's not Wikipedia, it'd be "own research" all the way. To be fair quite often you can go "oh, I wonder what does this Id is" by simply pasting it in your address bar after `https://instance.salesforce.com/` like with any other id...

Comment: This is astounding that it is not easily available documentation. Thanks for sharing. Great info.

Answer (score 2):

I ran the following SOQL query in Workbench to confirm nivyaj's experience:

```
SELECT CreatedById, CreatedBy.Name, Name,OwnerId FROM Report
```

Here's what I noticed: whenever a report was created by one of our inactive users, its `OwnerId` was set to the report's folder. I suspect that while some objects must be "owned" by an active user (e.g. Accounts, Leads, Opportunities), reports are not one of them.