# Could not retrieve standard folder Names when we query Folder Object

Tags: force.com, webservices, metadata-api

I am trying to query all the standard reports using folder object in salesforce. I am able to collect all the attributes except Folder Name.

I am using the same query to retrieve the custom folder names which I could make it. But it does not works for the standard folders.

Following is the query which I am using.

```
listFolders=[Select Id, Name, AccessType, Type, IsReadOnly, DeveloperName 
             From Folder 
             Where Type = 'Report'];
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid you'll need 2 queries to achieve that.

Report folders are funny, check [how is the report owner set?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10766/how-is-the-report-owner-set)

The relationship between Folder and Report is visible when you run describes but it has no name so it can't be used.

You can't go "up"

```
SELECT Id, Name, OwnerId, Owner.Name
FROM Report
```

And you can't go "down"

```
SELECT Id, Name, DeveloperName,
    (SELECT Id, Name, DeveloperName FROM Reports)
FROM Folder
```

Because of that I don't think even participating in the pilot "polymorphic SOQL" thingie will help you...

---

Build a `Map<Id, Folder> = new Map<Id, Folder>([your original query here])` and manually match with result of one of these

```
// 1
SELECT Id, Name, OwnerId
FROM Report
WHERE OwnerId IN :yourMap.keyset()
// or 
// WHERE OwnerId IN (SELECT Id FROM Folder WHERE Type = 'Report')

// 2 - should give same results
SELECT Id, Name, OwnerId, Owner.Name
FROM Report
WHERE OwnerId != :UserInfo.getUserId() AND OwnerId != :UserInfo.getOrganizationId()
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks @eyescream for the response. I think, I would asked the question slightly in a different way. Question:I need to query all the report FOLDERs with their DeveloperName. I am able to achieve the same for Custom Folders, but not for Standard Folders. Hope you may clear now.

Comment: Uh, no idea then. Dev. Name will be blank, all reports there are special (don't have Ids but long weird URLs), you also can't save new reports to these...