# Apex retrieve report folder names

Tags: apex, reporting, folder, reports-folder

I am trying to retrieve report folders through `Apex`. I can get the `Folder` id but not its name. It is coming as null for standard report folders

```
List<folder> FolderList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Folder WHERE Type ='Report'];
```

Can any body help me how to get name of `Folder`?

Comment: Same question here [Could not retrieve standard folder Names when we query Folder Object](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12477/could-not-retrieve-standard-folder-names-when-we-query-folder-object). Has a bit of background but no answer.

Comment: I've deleted my answer as I hadn't read the question properly (and it didn't add anything)..

Answer (score -1):

Standard report folders do not return Name by query. However, using Api call you can get all report folder names along with the report. See detailed explanation here.
https://glazeforce.wordpress.com/2016/02/03/get-all-reports-along-with-their-folder-name-and-report-data/