# How can I use the API to get a list of reports in the Unfiled Public Report folder?

Tags: apex, api, reporting

Short story: What is the best way to query for a list of reports in the 'Unfiled Public Report' folder.

Long story:

When I want to get a list of reports from a specific folder in apex I make a SOQL query like this:

`SELECT Id,Name FROM Report WHERE OwnerId = :folderId`

When I want a list of reports from Unfiled Public Reports in apex how would I do that? As far as I know Unfiled Publif Reports doesn't have a folder id.

I was able to get a list of reports by using the OwnerId of the organization. Like this:

`SELECT Id,Name FROM Report WHERE OwnerId = :OrgID`

Only was able to find that from [this question about setting owner](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10766/how-is-the-report-owner-set/10770#10770).

Turns out the OwnerId is a great way to get the list. Using the way of getting the OrgId programmatically from frontendloader my code turned out like this.

`[SELECT Id,Name from Report WHERE OwnerID = :UserInfo.getOrganizationId()];`

Interesting note: Found an answer on the Salesforce IdeaExchange from 5 years ago that talks about the folder name being `unfiled$public` but I am unable to get that to work. Also can't find confirmation of that. Only see it in [unrelated source code here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_report.htm).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to have answered your own question here.

Any report in the 'Unfiled Public Reports' folder will have an `OwnerId` of your OrgId. You should be able to reference your OrgId programmatically when you query for it, something like:

```
[SELECT Id,Name from Report WHERE OwnerID = :UserInfo.getOrganizationId()];
```

Comment: I didn't want to use OwnerId because I didn't know if only unfiled reports would have that set, but re-reading the OwnerId answer, turns out it is constant. My code turned out exactly as you suggested. Thanks!